# Match SaveAs2 Dialog File Type To Application.FileDialog

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

Say you want to have a button that the user can click and save a copy of the current file as a PDF([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx)):

```
Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:="fileName.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

This works fine, the user is presented with a save dialog, selects a location and the file is saved, however a few things are not correct:

[image]

The type displayed does not match what was specified in the VBA, how can this be correct? It still saves as type "PDF" without issue, even after showing "DOCX" as the file type in the "Save as Type" drop down. Also the "fileName.pdf" is not placed in the "File Name" box, its as if the dialog box is unaware of the options set in the VBA code([This same issue is also referenced in this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7e8acda-fbd7-4f86-8aba-fe9ebe9570b4/prevent-file-save-dialog-appearing?forum=exceldev)).

**UPDATE 1**

After taking a second look at my code I now realize that the SaveAs2 Method was not displaying the dialog menu, the correct version of the code(simplified) can be described as:

```
Dim selected As String: selected = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show()
Dim filePath As String

If selected <> 0 Then
    filePath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
    Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:=Split(filePath, ".")(0), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
End If
```

So then the real question(I guess) is how do you get "Application.FileDialog" to display the proper type you wish to save in under the "Save as type" drop down, and this has already been answered by @PatricK. Thanks everyone for the help, I apologize for the initial confused nature of this question.

Comment: A long shot, but the answer to this question could be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360555/document-save-is-showing-saveas-dialog

Comment: Dave, I agree with Patrick's remark about no dialog should be showing. Is it possible that your code (or someone else's) is trapping the DocumentBeforeSave event and forcing display of the dialog box? (Although I have no idea why using his code would suppress that...)

Comment: Yes I think my example is too simplistic, a bunch of stuff was going on before this method was being called, I don't even think that this code was responsible for displaying the popup box as I stated earlier, I will re-frame the question to reflect a more generic(+ accurate) request following the standard way to display the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised for `SaveAs2` will bring you a prompt to be honest - Only a new document and `.Save` will bring you that prompt.

If you want to get something similar to that prompt, you use [Application.FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840210(v=office.14).aspx) with type [msoFileDialogSaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432520(v=office.12).aspx).

Use this code below (perhaps as an AddIn suits more):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MySaveAs()
    Dim oPrompt As FileDialog, i As Long, sFilename As String
    Set oPrompt = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With oPrompt
        ' Find the PDF Filter from Default Filters
        For i = 1 To .Filters.Count
            'Debug.Print i & " | " & .Filters(i).Description & " | " & .Filters(i).Extensions
            ' Locate the PDF filter
            If InStr(1, .Filters(i).Description, "PDF", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                .FilterIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ' Change the title and button text
        .Title = "Saving """ & ActiveDocument.Name & """ to PDF format"
        .ButtonName = "Save to PDF"
        ' Default name
        .InitialFileName = ActiveDocument.Name
        ' Show the Prompt and get Filename
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sFilename = .SelectedItems(1)
            Debug.Print "Final filename: " & sFilename
            ' Save the file as PDF
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 sFilename, wdFormatPDF
        End If
    End With
    Set oPrompt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Screenshot sample:
[image: ResultingFileDialogBox]

Comment: There may be another unrelated issue with the file(read-only, permissions, etc..), I think that might be causing the dialog to be shown, I'll have to look into that further, but I think it lies outside of the scope of this question, this solution appears to work great for the time being. Thanks :)